# Eager Load Nested One-to-One Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now using a repository, I loaded a person from the database but I also want to eager load it's `Address` property and the address' `Country` property. I use the following code to load an immediate navigation property.

```
context.Entry(person).Reference(p => p.Address).Load();
```

Now my problem is how to load the `Country` navigation property of the loaded `Address` property. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the query for the reference then call include (but you will have to enumerate e.g. `.ToArray()` as there will be no `Load()` method to call - not to worry, EF will hook up the nav property of your original entity):

```
var navPropQuery = context.Entry(person).Reference(p => p.Address).Query()
    as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Address>;

navPropQuery.Include( "Country" ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is it possible to just load the property and not return it? For example, I will simply past the person entity to the method, after the method executes, the person contains all the values of the navigation properties. I don't want to return the actual values of the navigation property. I just want to load them on the existing entity.

Comment: notice I don't save the results of the call to `.ToArray()` - since the result of the `.Include(string)` call will be an `IQueryable`, you will need to enumerate it to execute the query, but the results will all be in their right place as `person.Address` and `person.Address.Country`